# asp.net TextBox not updating in IE11

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer-11, incompatibility

I have migrated my .net projet from framework 3.5 to 4.5 and my the site was previously running under IE7.
I need to run it under IE11 now.  I have a page which upon selecting an element in a dropdown display the values of the element selected.
The element has 3 different fields:
Code, name and info et a button delete which upon clicking delete the element and empty the fields.
Below is the code which does the reset:

```
        protected void LB_Supprimer_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
            if ( this.DBDelete_TRF() ) 
                {
                    this.TB_NOM.Text = "" ;
                    this.TB_CODE.Text = "" ;
                    this.TB_ACTCORR.Text = "" ;
                }           
        MngMessage.refresh();
    }
```

Code in aspx:

```
    <TABLE id="Table1" borderColor="lightgrey" cellSpacing="5" cellPadding="0" width="100%"
                                        border="0">
                                        <TR>
                                            <TD style="WIDTH: 168px; HEIGHT: 19px" align="right">
                                                <asp:Label id="Lbl_code" runat="server" CssClass="label" DESIGNTIMEDRAGDROP="47">Code : </asp:Label></TD>
                                            <TD style="WIDTH: 403px; HEIGHT: 19px">
                                                <asp:TextBox id="TB_CODE" runat="server" Width="96px" CssClass="txt" DESIGNTIMEDRAGDROP="73"
                                                    ToolTip="Code" Font-Bold="True" ontextchanged="TB_CODE_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>&nbsp;
                                            </TD>
                                        </TR>
                                        <TR>
                                            <TD style="WIDTH: 168px; HEIGHT: 68px" align="right">
                                                <asp:Label id="Label_Nom" runat="server" CssClass="label" DESIGNTIMEDRAGDROP="86">Nom : </asp:Label></TD>
                                            <TD style="WIDTH: 403px; HEIGHT: 68px">
                                                <asp:TextBox id="TB_NOM" runat="server" Height="54px" Width="360px" CssClass="txt" DESIGNTIMEDRAGDROP="85"
                                                    Font-Bold="True" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="4"></asp:TextBox></TD>
                                        </TR>
                                        <TR>
                                            <TD style="WIDTH: 168px" align="right"></TD>
                                            <TD style="WIDTH: 403px">
                                                <asp:Label id="LB_INFO" runat="server" CssClass="label">Info</asp:Label></TD>
                                        </TR>
                                        <TR>
                                            <TD style="WIDTH: 168px" align="right">
                                                <asp:Label id="Label8" runat="server" CssClass="label" DESIGNTIMEDRAGDROP="49">Action : </asp:Label>
                                                <asp:CheckBox id="chk_Confirmee" runat="server" CssClass="DBLabel" ToolTip="xxx yyy"
                                                    Text="Confirmée"></asp:CheckBox></TD>
                                            <TD style="WIDTH: 403px">
                                                <asp:TextBox id="TB_ACTCORR" runat="server" Height="74px" Width="360px" CssClass="txt" TextMode="MultiLine"
                                                    Rows="5"></asp:TextBox></TD>
                                        </TR>

                                        <TR>
                                            <TD align="center" height="15"><cc1:linkbutton id="LB_Supprimer" runat="server" DisableText="Traitement en cours" DisableAfterClick="True" onclick="LB_Supprimer_Click">Supprimer</cc1:linkbutton></TD>
                                        </TR>
                                    </TABLE>
```

The above does not work in IE11 only but in chrome it does.
Any idea how to solve this pls?

Comment: ... Are you creating your page layout by using a table?

Comment: @Tyler: I am not sure I get your question but this is the code how it is in the project.  I showed only part of the code.

Comment: `LB_Supprimer` is a UserControl and does not have an OnClick event. `LB_Supprimer_Click` will only trigger a javascript function (if there is one) but not a code behind method. What does `aspinlinkbutton` look like? Or is `onclick` a property?

Comment: @VDWWD : But when I click on LB_Supprimer in debug mode I can see that the fields are set to "".  It hits the function LB_Supprimer_Click.

Comment: What does the User Control look like?

Comment: @VDWWD : I am not I understand your question.

Comment: @tabby Were you the one who coded this, or did you hire someone to build your website?

Comment: `cc1:aspinlinkbutton` is not a standard Control like a LinkButton or a TextBox. I think it is a custom User Control and as such must have its own asxc and ascx.cs files.

Comment: @VDWWD : I did not code this. I am doing a migration here.  And it has its aspx.cs files.  The first part of the code if the aspx.cs

Comment: <cc1:aspinlinkbutton>...</cc1:linkbutton> check the closing tag

Comment: @Vitaly :  Sry, copy paste error